# Relative paths and nested includes

Tags: php, html, relative-path, include-path

I have a file navbar.php which is in folder views/general. It includes a few relative path files ../controllers/file1.php etc..

I can only include the navbar.php file in other files in the same views/general folder. If I try to include it in a file outside that, like views/signup,

the include paths contained in the navbar.php (../controllers/file1.php etc), won't be relevant anymore.

How can i solve that, so navbar.php can be used from anywhere ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar challenge and created a single file that defines constants for all the relevant paths that I want to be able to call as-needed. I include this file in all my pages (I define the $urlRoot so that this will work in all environments and is moveable do different domains, etc):

File: pathData.php (added MENUDIR for your example):

```
$baseDir = dirname(__DIR__) . '/';
$rootUrl = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
define('ROOTURL', $rootUrl);
define('BASEDIR', $baseDir);
define('INCLUDES', $baseDir . 'includes/');
define('INCLUDESURL', ROOTURL . 'includes/');
define('JQUERYURL', ROOTURL . 'includes/jquery/');
define('MENUDIR', ROOTURL . 'views/general/');
```

Then in each file, I include that file with an include that includes the relative directory path. For example:

```
include("pathData.php");
or
include("../pathData.php");
or
include("../../pathData.php); 
etc.
```

So in your case you could (depending on where your pathData file is):

```
include("../pathData.php");
include(MENUDIR . "navbar.php");
etc...
```

Comment: It works on windows as well as linux. :-)

Comment: @RyanVincent - just lucky there - I'm painfully unfamiliar with Windows. Ha!

Comment: This is a very typical approach used in many complex applications, and would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using PHP 5.3+**:

```
include __DIR__ . '/relative/path/from/this/file.php';
```

__DIR__ is a magic constant holding the absolute path of the current file.

**If you're using earlier versions of PHP**:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/relative/path/from/this/file.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also generalise everything from the root directory of your website hosting by using the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable which will be the directory where your `index.php` should be located.

Use as follows:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'path/from/root/website/location/to/file.php');
```